# Searching using regular expressions C++

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex

I'm using Boost.Regex to achieve something like this: search for a "|" and then take the left part of the "|" and put it a string, same with the right part:

```
string s1;
string s2;
who | sort
```

After this s1 should be "who" and s2 shoudl be "sort".
If I remember good, it was posible in Python, how can I do it using regular expressions in Boost ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
std::vector<std::string> strs;
boost::split(strs, "string to split", boost::is_any_of("|"));
```

[Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

Here's short sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
  // expression
  boost::regex exrp( "(.*)\\|(.*)" );
  boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
  // input
  std::wstring input = "who | sort";
  // search
  if( regex_search( input,  what, exrp ) ) {
    // found
    std::string s1( what[1].first, what[1].second );
    std::string s2( what[2].first, what[2].second );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Additionally you maybe want to look on [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm).